Is it possible to solve "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request" in case of URL Forwarding?
I have a domain name registered at Namecheap, and have URL Forwarding to the IP address of my home computer, which is running a Spring boot server.
The landing page has an Ajax call via fetch to an API end point on that server, and is hosted on a free web hosting site.
The server supplies all necessary CORS headers for the call to work when the URL in fetch is the actual IP address.
For obvious reason, I don't want to expose my real IP in plain sight like this, so I tried to replace the IP with the domain name, but once I do that, it fails with 'Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request'.
Is there a way to workaround this issue (without having to modify anything in the browser)?
